# a:hover при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: hover]

Доброго! При наведении курсора мыши каждый элемент списка должен менять цвет при наведении.

```
a:hover { color:whitesmoke; background: red;}
```

изменения работают но при этом background охватывает только текст , то есть серую область выше или ниже он не учитывает.
кусок верстки

```css
.top-nav {
 width: 960px;
 height: 48px;
 background-color: rgb(48,48,48);
 margin: auto;
 padding: auto;
}

.top-nav ul {
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: whitesmoke;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.top-nav a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: blue;
 background: red;
 width: 60px;
 height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Нужен кусок вёрстки и цсс, отвечающий за эту вёрстку. Так не ясно в чём проблема.

Comment: сейчас поправлю

Comment: И кусок html. Чтобы можно было здесь же воспроизвести.

Comment: Вы навешиваете ховер на ссылку, а надо на li

Comment: @humster_spb годный совет работает напиши комментарий как ответ, чтобы я мог закрыть вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы навешиваете ховер на ссылку, а надо на li